# Is there any way to make two edges parallel to each other?

Tags: modeling

I know there is a knife tool, but I already set uv map for my mesh, so i dont want to cut faces and have to set all the uv vertices of faces. Is there any way to make one edge parallel to another (not parallel to specific axis)?

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you have and then maybe annotate to show what you’re trying to do? I have no idea why the Knife tool would help.

Comment: @TheLabCat Yep. I just did. if you see my screenshot, i want to make 2.29 length edge to parallel to 2.34m one.(right one)

Answer (score 1):

Select 2.34 edge, go to transform selector and press the + button to create a new transform orientation.

Then switch to vertex edit mode, select one of the vertices of the 2.29 edge, press G, G to slide it on the opposite vertex location, confirm with enter then press G,Y and move it parallel to 2.34 vertex. Confirm where needed.

[image]

Comment: Wait a minute, “new transform orientation“? 

Comment: I forgot to add the picture, now it should be clearer.

Comment: Bro… That is so cool! Thanks for the tip.